# Altitudes of a hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry

I was doing my engineering graphics assignment and I came across this question

> A cone of base 60mm diameter and slant height 75mm rests with its base on the horizontal plane. It is cut by an auxiliarry inclined plane such that the true shape of the section is a
>   **hyperbola with a 40mm double ordinate and 50mm altitude**.

My question is:What is the double ordinate and altitude for a hypberbola?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what an altitude of a hyperbola is, however the *double ordinate* of a hyperbola is a chord perpendicular to the transverse axis.